# Understand the messages of GBWhatsapp.log

Tags: android

I need to understand this message that appears when I refresh the `GBWhatsapp.log`. The message is:

> WAContact/delete_photo_files /
>   data/data/com.gbwhatsapp/files/Avatars/(phone
>   number)@s.gbwhatsapp.net.j does not exist, nothing to delete.

Help me to understand what that message meant, thanks in advance.